# jruby rails undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, filterrific

I am trying to run filterrific in jruby rails environment. Initially, there was no errors and was able to run it succesffully. Few days after that I was working on different controller adding some other gems related with charts. When I came to student controller, now it is giving me this error, I have triple verified all the code and also did beyond compare with your demo app and mine. There was no changes in views, controller, model, js, db and config files, but suddenly I am getting this error "undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass" in the following line

```
.form-group.chardin_box{ :'data-position' => 'top', :'data-intro' => 'Filter by country.' }
  %label Category
  = f.select :with_country_id,
             @filterrific.select_options[:with_country_id],
             { :include_blank => '- Any -' },
             { :class => 'form-control' }
```

Application Trace:

```
app/views/students/index.html.haml:22:in block in _app_views_students_index_html_haml___1163931893_2080' app/views/students/index.html.haml:12:in_app_views_students_index_html_haml___1163931893_2080'
```

Full Trace:

```
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/select.rb:36:in grouped_choices?' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/select.rb:20:inrender'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:163:in select' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:817:inselect'
app/views/students/index.html.haml:22:in block in _app_views_students_index_html_haml___1163931893_2080' haml (5.0.1) lib/haml/helpers.rb:382:inblock in capture_haml'
haml (5.0.1) lib/haml/helpers.rb:667:in with_haml_buffer' haml (5.0.1) lib/haml/helpers.rb:378:incapture_haml'
haml (5.0.1) lib/haml/helpers/xss_mods.rb:62:in capture_haml_with_haml_xss' haml (5.0.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:45:incapture_with_haml'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:450:in form_for' haml (5.0.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_xss_mods.rb:29:inform_for_with_haml_xss'
filterrific (2.1.2) lib/filterrific/action_view_extension.rb:23:in form_for_filterrific' app/views/students/index.html.haml:12:in_app_views_students_index_html_haml___1163931893_2080'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in block in render' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:ininstrument'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in instrument_render_template' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:inrender'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in block in render_template' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:inblock in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in block in instrument' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:ininstrument'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in instrument' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:ininstrument'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:51:in block in render_template' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:inrender_with_layout'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50:in render_template' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:inrender'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in render_template' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:inrender'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in _render_template' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in_render_template'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in render_to_body' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:inrender_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in render_to_body' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:inrender'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in render' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:inblock in render'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in block in ms' /home/balaji/Documents/balaji/unl/PhD/railswebapp/jruby-9.1.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/benchmark.rb:308:inrealtime'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in ms' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:inblock in render'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in cleanup_view_runtime' activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:29:incleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in render' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:33:indefault_render'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in block in send_action' org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1747:intap'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in send_action' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:inprocess_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in process_action' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:inblock in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in run_callbacks' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:inprocess_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in process_action' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:inblock in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in block in instrument' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:ininstrument'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in instrument' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:inprocess_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in process_action' activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:inprocess_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in process' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:inprocess'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in dispatch' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:indispatch'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in dispatch' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:inserve'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:46:in block in serve' org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:ineach'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in serve' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:832:incall'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in call' rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:incall'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in call' torquebox-web-3.2.0 (java) lib/torquebox/session/servlet_store.rb:47:incall'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in call' activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:incall'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in block in call' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:inrun_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in call' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:incall'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in call' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:incall'
railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in call_app' railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:inblock in call'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in block in tagged' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:intagged'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in tagged' railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:incall'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in call' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:incall'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in call' rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:incall'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in call' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:incall'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in call' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:incall'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in call' railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:incall'
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of hustling somehow found a workaround, if anyone can better explain what was the issue it would be great. For those who wants the answer see below.

I changed the following line

```
= f.select :with_country_id,
             @filterrific.select_options[:with_country_id],
             { :include_blank => '- Any -' },
             { :class => 'form-control' }
```

into the below lines, basically I removed filterrific out of the select option and populated the select options in the form using ruby.

```
= f.select :with_country_id, Country.all.collect {|u| [u.name, u.id]}, 
                                        { :include_blank => '- Any -' },
                                        { :class => 'form-control' }
```